# How to add month to a date without changing day?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Let's consider the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
idx = pd.DatetimeIndex(["2019-07-15", "2019-08-15", "2019-09-15", "2019-10-15"])
DatetimeIndex(['2019-07-15', '2019-08-15', '2019-09-15', '2019-10-15'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

I would like to add one month to each date, but without changing its day.

In other words, the desired output is:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2019-08-15', '2019-09-15', '2019-10-15', '2019-11-15'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Do you have any idea how it can be done?

Answer (score 3):

Use [`pandas.DateOffset`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.DateOffset.html):

```
out = idx + pd.DateOffset(months=1)
```

output:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2019-08-15', '2019-09-15', '2019-10-15', '2019-11-15'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

*NB. be careful to use `months=1` and not `month=1` (without `s`), which would set all months to 01 (January).*