# How to automatically detect date frequency and add it to date?

Tags: python, pandas

Let's consider data with date format in four possible formats:

1. Monthly dates
2. Weekly dates
3. Daily dates (including weekends)
4. Business dates - only from Monday to Friday

I want to have a function that will automatically detect the time frequency of it and will add one period to it. (for example, if our dates has weekly frequency, we want to return those dates shifted by one week forward)

The function that I wrote is the following:

```
import pandas as pd

def add_period(idx):
    # If data has weekly frequency
    if pd.to_timedelta(np.diff(idx).min()).days == 7:
        return idx + pd.DateOffset(weeks=1)
    # If data has monthly frequency
    elif pd.to_timedelta(np.diff(idx).min()).days >=28:
        return idx + pd.DateOffset(months=1)
    # If data has buisness dates frequency
    elif pd.to_timedelta(np.diff(idx).max()).days == 3:
        return pd.bdate_range(start = idx[1], periods = len(idx))
    # If data has single dates frequency
    else:
        return idx + pd.DateOffset(days = 1)
```

However, I perceive this as little complicated with respect to what it is doing - just to detect data frequency and add one period of it to old data.

Do you have any idea how it can be simplified?

**EXAMPLE**

Let's consider monthly data:

```
idx = pd.DatetimeIndex(["2019-01-15", "2019-02-15", "2019-03-15", "2019-04-15", "2019-05-15", "2019-06-15", "2019-07-15", "2019-08-15", "2019-09-15", "2019-10-15", \
                        "2019-11-15", "2019-12-15"])
```

Then the output of the function is the following:

```
add_period(idx)
DatetimeIndex(['2019-02-15', '2019-03-15', '2019-04-15', '2019-05-15',
               '2019-06-15', '2019-07-15', '2019-08-15', '2019-09-15',
               '2019-10-15', '2019-11-15', '2019-12-15', '2020-01-15'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

which is a desired output - our function detected correctly, that date frequency is month frequency, and to each month it added a month.

Another (now tricky example):

```
idx = pd.DatetimeIndex(["2019-01-15", "2019-01-16", "2019-01-18", "2019-01-19", "2019-01-20", "2019-01-21", "2019-01-22"])
```

This date index has date frequency (no buisness dates), but it has a gap (there is no 2019-01-17). Our function will correctly detect this and shift it by one period

```
add_period(idx)
DatetimeIndex(['2019-01-16', '2019-01-17', '2019-01-19', '2019-01-20',
               '2019-01-21', '2019-01-22', '2019-01-23'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Comment: Is one of the `elif`s `.max()` on purpose?

Comment: yes, that on purpose, when you have buisness dates, then the maximal range should be equal to 3

Comment: Can you provide an example dataset? I imagine this is in link with [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73498623/16343464)?

Comment: I edited my question with an example

Comment: Can you provide one example for each type of frequency that you expect? (or at least a few ones, with the potentially tricky ones)

Comment: Also are the dates successive and ordered (in their period) or can there be gaps?

Comment: Desirably if we could account for gaps it would be perfect

Comment: I added another tricky example, please, let me know if you need more